# "ejs.render" is calling next route

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

when I enter in http://localhost/client, display 404.

```
app.get('/client', function(req, res) {
        ...
        ejs.render('any template', {});
        ...
        res.end();
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    console.log('404');
    ...
});
```

but if I remove "ejs.render" and put res.end('any html') works.
How can i use "ejs.render" and not call 404? Thanks. It's a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `ejs` for use EJS with express.
 The Express application generator uses Jade as its default, but it also supports several others (Like `ejs`, `pug`, etc).

For example:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// use res.render to load up an ejs view file

// index page 
app.get('/client', function(req, res) {
    res.render('pages/index'); //does not needs ejs extension
});

app.get('*', function(req, res){
 res.send('what???', 404);
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('8080 is the magic port');
```

When you make a request to the home page, the index.ejs file will be rendered as `HTML`.

See the official documentation [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html).

Comment: I also tried using res.render, I Define     app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); all OK, works. The problem is that the "app.get('*');" is being called too

Comment: Since `app.get('*', ...)` will match any GET request, the request will never reach the `/client` handler.

Comment: what @robertklep said is the problem Mario

Comment: @SayuriMizuguchi simple fix: move the `*` handler _below_ the `/client` handler.

Comment: Edited with sucess, thanks for your explanation @robertklep. If you want to answer the question, you were the key to the answer. All greetings for you.

Comment: OK robertklep, Thanks. But if you remove res.render(...) from '/client', app.get('*', ...) doesn't called nevertheless. SO, I Remove app.get('*', ...), It's fixed, Thanks

Comment: HI @MarioLopes, i know you're new here, mark the answer if it follows the [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) guide and help other's to solves the same problem.